# How to get access to the application's Bundle.main or info.plist in Swift 5.9 Macro?

Tags: swift, swift-macro

How can I get an access to the Bundle.main of the application inside the Macro? Basically I need to read the info.plist. Even more specifically, I have props there linked to my `.xcconfig` props, and want to read and validate configs in compile time.

I have tried:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
```

and getting the **bundle of the Macro** itself

I've tried also:

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myorg.AppName")
//"com.myorg.AppName" is the correct identifier of my app bundle, which I've double checked from the app itself
```

And getting `nil`

Any way to get the **app's** bundle/info.plist inside the Macro?
We can't just pass the object to macro props, because it's pre-compile operation.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Macros run in a sandboxed environment, with no access to the file system or network.

Answer (score 0):

There are few cases to note when using macros here:

1. Macros run during compile time, while bundle is only available when you are running the final compiled app. So macros can't use bundles here as during compilation it is not available.
2. Your next option is accessing the file using current file system, but as of now macros don't have any access to file system but there is plan to add this in future:

> The macro expansion operation is asynchronous, to account for potentially-asynchronous operations that will eventually be added to `MacroExpansionContext`. For example, operations that require additional communication with the compiler to get types of subexpressions, **access files in the program**, and so on.

So as of now your option is to use swift package plugins instead, create a build tool plugin that performs validation during build phase of the app. You can get more details on following resources on how to achieve what you want:

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110359/
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110401/